# Pandas.to_datetime function fails silently

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm having some difficulty with pandas to_datetime function, and datetimes in general in pandas. Specifically, to_datetime is failing silently when applied to a pandas series, without doing anything, and I have to explicitly iterate over each value individually to get the function to work properly, even though (at least according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690738/in-pandas-how-do-i-convert-a-string-of-date-strings-to-datetime-objects-and-put)) both should work the same.

```
In [81]: np.__version__
Out[81]: '1.6.1'

In [82]: pd.__version__
Out[82]: '0.12.0'

In [83]: a[0:10]
Out[83]: 
0    8/31/2013 14:57:00
1    8/31/2013 13:55:00
2    8/31/2013 15:45:00
3     9/1/2013 13:26:00
4     9/1/2013 13:56:00
5     9/2/2013 13:55:00
6     9/3/2013 13:33:00
7     9/3/2013 14:11:00
8     9/3/2013 14:35:00
9     9/4/2013 14:28:00
Name: date_time, dtype: object

In [84]: a[0]
Out[84]: '8/31/2013 14:57:00'

In [85]: a=pd.to_datetime(a)

In [86]: a[0]
Out[86]: '8/31/2013 14:57:00'

In [87]: a=[pd.to_datetime(date) for date in a]

In [88]: a[0]
Out[88]: Timestamp('2013-08-31 14:57:00', tz=None)
```

Any thoughts about why this is? I seem to be having trouble in general with this data and the date_time column not being parsed correctly, and I suspect it may have something to do with this failure.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Does it work for `pd.to_datetime(a[0:10])`?

Comment: This seems to work for me with numpy 1.7 and pandas 0.12.

Comment: consider upgrading to numpy 1.7.1

Comment: Hmm, I seem to have a collision between Numpy versions on my Mac, between the pre-installed system version and my PIP version. Once I resolve that I'll respond here... Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with pd.to_datetime(s, errors='raise') ? +1 to other answers to upgrade.

Comment: @AndyHayden, yup, that was it. There was one malformed date in the column that was causing the whole conversion to fail!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed in new pandas, the default errors kwarg is 'raise' rather than 'ignore'.
The new behavior is:

```
In [21]: pd.to_datetime(dates)  # same as errors='raise'
...
ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime.

In [22]: pd.to_datetime(dates, errors="ignore")  # the original problem
Out[22]:
0    1/1/2014
1           A
dtype: object
```

That is, `to_datetime` no longer fails silently!

The old answer is kept below...

---

As DaveA points out (after checking my comment), by default to_datetime fails silently if there is an issue and returns what was originally passed:

```
In [1]: dates = pd.Series(['1/1/2014', 'A'])

In [2]: pd.to_datetime(dates)  # doesn't even convert first date
Out[2]: 
0    1/1/2014
1           A
dtype: object

In [3]: pd.to_datetime(dates, errors='raise')
...
ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime.
```

Note: This argument used to be `coerce=True` in older pandas versions.

```
In [4]: pd.to_datetime(dates, errors='coerce')
Out[4]: 
0   2014-01-01
1          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

*This behavior [`to_datetime` is discussed in the timeseries section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps).*

You can see which dates failed to parse by checking [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.common.isnull.html):

```
In [5]: dates[pd.isnull(pd.to_datetime(dates, errors='coerce'))]
Out[5]: 
1    A
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas.to_datetime function fails silently, and simply returns the original value if it fails. One single malformed input can cause the entire process to fail silently.