# ValueError: day is out of range for month

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a string from a dataframe to datetime.

```
dfx = df.ix[:,'a']
dfx = pd.to_datetime(dfx)
```

But it gives the following error:

> ValueError: day is out of range for month

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the value of `dfx`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690738/in-pandas-how-do-i-convert-a-string-of-date-strings-to-datetime-objects-and-put

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Pandas how do I convert a string of date strings to datetime objects and put them in a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690738/in-pandas-how-do-i-convert-a-string-of-date-strings-to-datetime-objects-and-put)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Maybe help add parameter `dayfirst=True` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), if format of datetime is `30-01-2016`:

```
dfx = df.ix[:,'a']
dfx = pd.to_datetime(dfx, dayfirst=True)
```

More universal is use parameter [`format`](http://strftime.org/) with `errors='coerce'` for replacing values with other `format` to `NaN`:

```
dfx = '30-01-2016'

dfx = pd.to_datetime(dfx, format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='coerce')
print (dfx)
2016-01-30 00:00:00
```

Sample:

```
dfx = pd.Series(['30-01-2016', '15-09-2015', '40-09-2016'])
print (dfx)
0    30-01-2016
1    15-09-2015
2    40-09-2016
dtype: object

dfx = pd.to_datetime(dfx, format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='coerce')
print (dfx)
0   2016-01-30
1   2015-09-15
2          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If format is standard (e.g. `01-30-2016` or `01-30-2016`), add only `errors='coerce'`:

```
dfx = pd.Series(['01-30-2016', '09-15-2015', '09-40-2016'])
print (dfx)
0    01-30-2016
1    09-15-2015
2    09-40-2016
dtype: object

dfx = pd.to_datetime(dfx, errors='coerce')
print (dfx)
0   2016-01-30
1   2015-09-15
2          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well in my case

```
year = 2023
month = 2
date = datetime.date(year, month, 30)
```

got me this error because February month has 29 or 28 days in it. Maybe that point helps someone