# calculate event duration pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am attempting to follow this first answer of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352279/calculating-the-duration-an-event-in-a-time-series-python) for calculating an event duration. The example in the post is rainfall duration and the person wants to know a totalization of the rainfall and a duration in hours of the rainfall event.

My scenario is a similar time series but the application is a pump and I am wanting to know a totalized duration in hours per day that the pump runs. My data is a pump speed command, and anytime the pump speed is greater than 0.0 the pump is running.

To start with, I am reading my CSV file into Pandas.

```
#read CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\data.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

# Converting the index as date
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df
```

Except I am running into an issue when attempting to convert my `Date` index into date time. This returns a `ValueError: day is out of range for month`

Would anyone know  a fix for this? Ultimetely this is the code that I am attempting to recreate from the SO post 1st answer where the author is creating help columns...

```
# create helper columns defining contiguous blocks and day
df['block'] = (df['Pump4VFD'].astype(bool).shift() != df['Pump4VFD'].astype(bool)).cumsum()
df['day'] = df.index.dt.normalize()

# group by day to get unique block count and value count
session_map = df[df['value'].astype(bool)].groupby('day')['block'].nunique()
hour_map = df[df['value'].astype(bool)].groupby('day')['value'].count()

# map to original dataframe
df['sessions'] = df['day'].map(session_map)
df['hours'] = df['day'].map(hour_map)

# calculate result
res = df.groupby(['day', 'hours', 'sessions'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()
res['duration'] = res['hours'] / res['sessions']
res['amount'] = res['value'] / res['sessions']
```

My data looks like this:

```
                    Pump4VFD
Date                                                                    
1/0/00 12:45 AM          0.0
1/0/00 12:50 AM          0.0
1/0/00 12:55 AM          0.0
1/0/00 12:00 AM          0.0
1/0/00 1:05 AM           0.0
```

Comment: what is the format date you want initial date -> final date sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add dayfirst=True to pd.to_datetime

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,dayfirst=True)
```

This might be one way to go about;but if does not work then try the following addition:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,dayfirst=True,infer_datetime_format=True)
```

If you need further clarification try this post:[ValueError: day is out of range for month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285365/valueerror-day-is-out-of-range-for-month)