# how to convert object column in to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a column type to datetime

Value Format in Column: `'2016-04-10 12:17:52'`

```
df['dropoff_time']

output
0      2016-04-10 12:17:52
1      2016-04-13 06:44:12
2      2016-04-13 06:54:43
3      2016-04-13 08:33:50
Name: created_at_new, Length: 328, dtype: object
```

I am trying the following code:

```
df['created_at_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at_new'])
```

> ValueError: day is out of range for month

Desired result is a datetime

```
('2010-11-12 00:00:00')
```

Comment: You have an invalid date, as the error suggests. Try with `pd.to_datetime(df['created_at_new'], errors='coerce')` to set it to a `NaT`

Comment: Works for me with your sample data.

Comment: probably oyu have something like: 2018-02-30, a date which not exists!!!

Comment: Thank you guys, it worked, df['created_at_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at_new'], errors='coerce')

Answer (score 0):

When I tried with the same example, it worked for me. Anyways in order to rectify the error, you can try the following:

- Check whether you have the latest version of pandas. If not Update it and
- Try mentioning the date format

df['created_at_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at_new'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

- Still, if it doesn't work. You can skip the one with error using the argument errors='coerce'. In the place of the skipped one, 'NaT' value will be added.

For more details, you check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285365/valueerror-day-is-out-of-range-for-month).