# Converting improper float to date

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

My dataframe has dates like this

```
dates
9112015.0
20032015.0
16042014.0
```

I have tried this

```
pd.to_datetime(fraud_df['DATEOPENEDDISBURSED'], format='%d%m%Y',dayfirst=True)
```

But it is giving me ValueError: day is out of range for month

Comment: cannot reproduce, works fine for me. What's your Python/pandas version? Btw. if you set a `format`, you don't need to specify `dayfirst`.

Comment: Possible duplicates 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285365/valueerror-day-is-out-of-range-for-month

Comment: @FObersteiner 3.9.7

Comment: which line (i.e. which date) exactly throws the error?

Comment: first line itself

Comment: ok this might be a platform-specific thing; try to convert the column to integer, then to string, then zfill with zeros to get zero-prefixed days - `fraud_df['DATEOPENEDDISBURSED'].astype('int').astype('str').str.zfill(8)`.

Comment: @FObersteiner apparently column contains NaN as well so getting this IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to

- fill the NaNs
- convert to string
- and zfill with zeros to get zero-prefixed days consistently

EX:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.Series([9112015.0,20032015.0,16042014.0,np.nan])

# to get zero-prefixed days: to integer, then to string and zfill with zeros
dates = dates.fillna(-1).astype('int').astype('str').str.zfill(8)

# to datetime and coerce errors, giving NaT for the NaNs in the initial Series
pd.to_datetime(dates, format="%d%m%Y", errors='coerce')
0   2015-11-09
1   2015-03-20
2   2014-04-16
3          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.to_datetime(fraud_df['DATEOPENEDDISBURSED'], format='%-d%m%Y',dayfirst=True)
```

from the **Python strftime cheatsheet**  https://strftime.org/:

`%-d    8   Day of the month as a decimal number. (Platform specific)`

Comment: ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-d%m%Y'

Comment: Does removing `dayfirst=True` help?

Comment: No it doesn't help